# Show control hierarchy in the WinForms designer

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, .net-2.0, designer

One of our clients has an old WinForms application that contains forms with a lot of controls on them. Some of those controls have a deep hierarchy and that makes it to hard to select them in the designer.

I need to understand this hierarchy to make modifications to the application to correct some bugs. Is there a way to see this hierarchy clearly? For example, is there something available that is similar to what can be seen in an .aspx source file when you have a breadcrumb of where you are in the HTML hierarchy (HTML > Body > div > etc.)? Or something more visual maybe?

Answer (score 225, accepted):

You need to use the Document Outline

```
View > Other Windows > Document Outline
```

Or via hotkey

```
Ctl + ALT + T
```

Comment: Who knew?  This also answers the question: I need to make my existing form a page of a tab control, that is, I want to surround the existing form with a new tab control container.  How do I do that?  You create the tab control on your form then maneuver the up/down/left/right arrows in the Document Outline window until you've got the arrangement you want.

Answer (score 17):

Click on **View > Other Windows > Document Outline** in Visual Studio.

That should show the control hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Style Builder for UI Customization - Download this tool and use it...

Another tool is present which is "Control Spy Tool for Easier Development"

You will find the solution easily..