# Controls containing map

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Delphi IDE has nice map that shows which control contains which. Is it possible to see the same in Visual Studio c#?

[image]

Comment: Are you asking for a list of IDE's for C# that provide this feature?

Comment: One of those rare question where an IDE tag like Visual Studio (or whatever IDE is used) would improve it

Comment: Windows Forms? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004488/show-control-hierarchy-in-the-winforms-designer